# Is it possible for me to have a parent Gruntfile.js interact or run tasks on a child Gruntfile.js?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am build a framework that allows for the creation of modular "apps" within the parent application eco-system.

The parent application will have a Gruntfile.js at it's root, and then there will be child "apps" deeper in the folder structure that i'd like to allow to have their own Gruntfile's.

See below:

```
/application
|-- Gruntfile.js
|-- /apps
|---- /modularApp1
|------ Gruntfile.js
|---- /modularApp2
|------ Gruntfile.js
```

Is anyone aware of a way to handle this in Grunt 0.4? Do I need to create my own Grunt task to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm working on a project with a very similar setup. I use the [grunt-hub](https://github.com/shama/grunt-hub) task to run tasks on my "child apps" and it mostly works great. I had some small issues with the suggested method of running watch tasks, so instead I just simply use grunt-hub to execute the watch tasks on the child apps.

Here's a basic example of my hub config:

```
hub: {
  src: [
    'protected/modules/*/Gruntfile.js'
  ],
  default: {
    src: '<%= hub.src %>',
    tasks: [
      'default'
    ]
  },
  build: {
    src: '<%= hub.src %>',
    tasks: [
      'build'
    ]
  },
  watch: {
    src: '<%= hub.src %>',
    tasks: [
      'watch'
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make those single tasks (build, watch) automatically handled? I mean: grunt hub:test -> automatically search for all test targets in child gruntfiles